# Hibernate Annotation, how to use @Joincolumn refer to a foreign key?

Tags: hibernate, annotations

I use Hibernate 3.6.8. Here is my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE UTILIZATION (
ID BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY 
... 
FK_WORKCATEGORY SMALLINT,
CONSTRAINT PK_UTILIZATION PRIMARY KEY ( ID));

CREATE TABLE DB2ADMIN.WORKCATEGORY(
ID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(50),
CONSTRAINT PK_WORKCATEGORY PRIMARY KEY(ID));

ALTER TABLE UTILIZATION ADD FOREIGN KEY (FK_WORKCATEGORY) REFERENCES WORKCATEGORY(ID);
```

my Pojos:

```
@Entity
@Proxy(proxyClass=IWorkCategory.class)
@Table(name="WORKCATEGORY")
public class WorkCategory extends BoBase implements Serializable, IWorkCategory{

    @Id
    private Integer Id;
    private String description;

    @Override
    public Serializable getId() {
        return Id;
    }
    @Override
    public void setId(Serializable id) {
        Id = (Integer)id;
    }
    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    @Override
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }   
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Proxy(proxyClass=IUtilization.class)
@Table(name="UTILIZATION")
public class Utilization extends BoBase implements Serializable, IUtilization{

    @Id     
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long Id;    

    private WorkCategory workCategory;


    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=WorkCategory.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_WORKCATEGORY", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    public WorkCategory getWorkCategory() {
        return workCategory;
    }


    public void setWorkCategory(WorkCategory workCategory) {
        this.workCategory = workCategory;
    }
}
```

As you can see the table Utilization refer to table `WorkCategory` by foreign key `FK_WORKCATEGORY`, but in `Utilization` pojo, i declare this property with the name `workCategory`.
When I run unit test for `Utilization bo = UtilizationDAO.get(new Long(123))`, the SQL is generated with the column UTILIZATIO0_.**WORKCATEGORY**, instead of `FK_WORKCATEGORY`.
I have put the **@JoinColumn(name="FK_WORKCATEGORY"**, in the `Utilization` Pojo, but it doesn't help.
Please help me to fix this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you put your annotation on the getter rather than putting in on the field. Since the `@Id` annotation is put on a field, Hibernate expects all the annotations to be on fields.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, Can you please help me in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895585/hibernate-version-annotation-and-object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instanc

Comment: You fixed my exception. Would never have expected it to be something as simple as this. thanks man!